# Change color of subelements by mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have the following Window bar with four buttons and one image (a littlebit like ribbon):

[image]

this is the code (XAML) and the code behind (in C#) is not interesting :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Focusable="False"
    Click="SaveClicked" Margin="10, 0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image x:Name="ImageSave" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20"
           Source="images/titlebar/SaveIconWhite.png" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
        <Label x:Name="LbSave" Content="Save" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="14"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The code is nearly the same for the other buttons.

The buttons feel a littlebit unhandy because they have no mouseover effects.
I would like to implement a color change of the labels when the mouse is over the buttons. a change of the images for file load and save would be great too, but i think i am able to do it myself when i know how to implement the mouse over color change of the label.

under normal conditions i'd try to archieve a mouse over color change with these code:

```
<Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </Button.Style>
```

But this does not work, because i already have the Button.Template and i am also a littlebit confused about the Button.Template at all (haven't understood it - only copied..). How is the Button.Template working and what is it usage?

Is anybody able to give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at [Visual States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx), which would be defined at the top level element of your Button Template.

Comment: @Clemens found this link few seconds ago. i will have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

We have [MouseEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MouseLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Events.

Use `MouseEnter` to Change the Color When Mouse is inside control.

Use `MouseLeave` to Change back the Color When Mouse comes out of the control.

Comment: Yeah sure this is an option, but i'd like to know how to archieve this in XAML.

Comment: im not saying not to use xaml. but at this point i guess codebehind is easier. however thats your choice. @JensHorstmann

Comment: i agree. but because this does not answer the question in XAML i can't accept it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Never Used but Put Trigger inside ControlTemplate of button:
Something Like This:

```
<Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter TargetName="buttonLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
           </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

and How is the Button.Template working and what is it usage?
visit the link below
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84630/WPF-Customize-your-Application-with-Styles-and-Con

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273.aspx
Hope it may help you.